# Como eu crio uma classe em Java que seja do tipo: MinhaClasse<T extends Comparable<T>>?

Tags: java

Eu estou tentando iniciar uma classe que é um bubble sort que extends uma classe chamada Comparable. O meu código está assim:

```
public final class BubbleSortPassPerItem<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Sorter<T> {
    public void sort(final T[] items) {
        for (int pass=0; pass<items.length; pass++) {
            for (int i=0; i<items.length-1; i++) {
                if (items[i].compareTo(items[i+1])>0) {
                    final T item = items[i];
                    items[i] = items[i+1];
                    items[i+1] = item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Não entendo muito bem como funcionam essas classes parametrizadas. Como eu faço para iniciar essa classe no Main método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lógica de inicialização do seu exemplo é a mesma de quando é criado um array utilizando generics. Voce vai colocar o nome da Classe que atende aos critérios de herança que você citou dentro de <>
Ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
SuaClasseBubbleSort<ClasseQueHerdaDeComparable> bubbleSort = new SuaClasseBubbleSort<>();
```

A classe que você informar dentro de <> deve ter implementada a interface Comparable.

Recomendo dar uma pesquisada na internet sobre Java Generics, o assunto é fácil de compreender.